# Firestore .for is not iterable

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

This code is giving me an error '.for is not iterable':

```
const colRef = db.collection('tenants').doc(tenantId).collection('supplies')
const items = []
const query = colRef.where('stockGrams', '>', 0) // Get all items with stock left
const querySnapshot = await query.get()
if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => { // Error occurs here!
    items.push(doc.data()) // Add each item to our list
  })
}
```

Tried something simple:

```
const querySnapshot = await colRef.limit(5).get()
```

but still get the same error.

Sorry, did some more testing. It seems the line of code AFTER  that is causing the problem:

```
if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => { // Error occurs here!
    items.push(doc.data()) // Add each item to our list
  })
}
for (const [item, index] of items) { ... // This is where the error occurs
```

If I comment this last block out, I don't get the the '.for is not iterable' error.
So it's not the querySnapshot.forEach that's triggering it.

Still don't understand the problem.
OK I found it! To get the index when iterating an array, I need to use its 'entries' property...

```
for (const [item, index] of items.entries()) {
```

It's working now. Sorry to bother you.
Still learning this stuff.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the full error output for this problem, and make it clear how you tied that error to the specific line of code?  You should be able to call [forEach on a QuerySnapshot object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot#querysnapshotforeach) with no problem.  Also share the SDK you're using and its version.